# List of attributes inheriting their values from parents by default

Tags: css

We can easily see that some CSS attributes inherit their values from parents by default (like `font-size`) and some other don't. I'd like to get the full list of the first and the second ones.

Comment: sry can u plz explain clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not peer-reviewed but check-out https://github.com/igoradamenko/inherited-css-properties